# Is it okay to use var on purpose in ES6, as opposed to let?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, coding-standards, es6

I was *really* glad that ES6 introduced the `let` keyword for defining variables. `var` scoping rules can lead to all kinds of issues, especially when working with loops and event handlers. Even when programmers used `var` in the past, they still almost always *expected* `let` scoping rules.

Variables declared with `var` are available in the entire function. Variables defined with `let` are only available inside the block where they are declared.

However, `var`'s scoping rules are also useful sometimes, though very rarely. Here is an example: (imagine all of these examples are inside a function, I don't intend to define globals here)

```
try {
    var result = mightThrowAnException();
    //do various things
}
finally {
    if (result) cleanup(result);
}
//do other things
callSomeFunction(result); //reference result

return result;
```

In the above example, replacing `var` with `let` would cause an error. In order to use `let`, one would have to write a function like this:

```
let result; //declare the variable outside the braces
try {
    result = mightThrowAnException();
    //do various things
}
finally {
    if (result) cleanup(result);
}
//do other things
callSomeFunction(result); //reference result

return result;
```

I honestly think writing it this way isn't any better. It feels worse when you have to predefine more variables like these, just because they're declared in a `try` block.

In TypeScript, there is the additional annoyance that you have to explicitly declare the type of `result` if you want to predefine it in this way. If you initialize it, the type will be deduced automatically.

Is it a good idea to use `var` instead of `let` to take advantage of these scoping rules, when in almost every other part of your code you use `let`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any reason to use the "var" keyword in ES6?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6)

Comment: In any case, I think your second example is the preferred way to do it.  Most other languages will not allow the `var` variation to work, so it violates the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 5):

Usually in these types of questions, I refer the ESLint for guidance as they explain very plainly why the rules are as they are, take a look at [no-var](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var) rule.

The main reason is for readability. the behaviour you are referring to is hard to read and track and here is an [example](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/es6-variable-scopes-in-loops-with-closure-9cde7a198744) .

Also, the second snippet of code is by far easier to track and debug, and defining the variable in the **correct** scope (first example the var is used outside the scope of definition, which is misleading and can cause problems like [*shadowing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript) ).